# OOP code - sharing data between state objects

Tags: java, c#, c++, oop

Our legacy code is written in such a way, that the master class holds a state and every so often does this kind of update: `NewState = CurrentState->UpdateState()`

The issue is that one is `ReadyState` and the other is `RefreshingState`. As it is now, the ReadyState would have to check the time to refresh and if the time is right, call return the RefreshingState in its UpdateState method.

However, the time to refresh is known only by the RefreshingState!

I cannot simply return it from the UpdateState method, at least not without modifying contract for another 20 classes that won't care about the time...

I have three questions:

1. What kind of OOP pattern would that be?
2. How should I share the time between the states properly with this pattern?
3. Is there a better way to write this altogether? (I CAN'T/WON'T rewrite it, I'm just curious)

Thank you.